# Migrating content between domains with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have two domains: domain1.com and domain2.com

I'm trying to migrate from domain1.com to domain2.com with a redirect.

but domain1.com and kf.domain1.com are serving the content (200 code) of domain2.com and the cert from domain2.com.

I've tried multiple combinations of things, I've trying putting the redirect in the server directive, or in a location, I've tried 301s and 308's I've tried moving "default_server" around, but nothing happens.

I put `ipv6only=on` in the domain1.com directive which should cause an error because it's in the file twice, and it also doesn't error.

I've triple checked that the domains are not typos (but I used %s/// to replace them so they can't be.)

I get no error messages in any logs, what could possibly be wrong with my config?

here's my `nginx -T`:

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

worker_processes  1;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so;



events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/fastcgi levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m inactive=24h;
    proxy_cache_path   /var/cache/nginx/proxy   levels=1:2 keys_zone=two:8m inactive=24h; 
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    ##
        # SSL settings
        ##
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        # Forward secrecy settings
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";


    include sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location = /images/test4kf2.png {
        root /var/www/kf2/;
    }

    location / {
        return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    }

    server {
    listen      433 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:433 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name domain1.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.com/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain1.com/error.log notice;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
    }


    server {
    server_name www.domain2.com domain2.com;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain2.com/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain2.com/error.log;

        root /var/www/domain1.com/;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location = / {
        index index.html;
    }

    location /hls {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';
        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /tmp;
    }

    location = /donate {
        return 307 https://www.paypal.com/<redacted>;
    }


}


    server {
    server_name kf.domain1.com;

    listen      433 ssl;
    listen [::]:433 ssl;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/kf.domain1.com/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/kf.domain1.com/error.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/kf.domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/kf.domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        return 301 https://kf.domain2.com$request_uri;
    }
    }



    server {
        listen      443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name kf.domain2.com;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/kf.domain2.com/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/kf.domain2.com/error.log;

    proxy_cache two;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location / { 
        proxy_cache two;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }

        location /images/ {
            gzip_static on;
        root /steam/kf2/KFGame/Web/;
        expires max;
    }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    } 
  # server {
  # listen      443 ssl default_server;
  # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  #
  # location / {
  #     return 404;
  # }}


}

rtmp {
    <redacted>;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg opus;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ignore1.com:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.ignore1.com ignore1.com coach.domain1.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/ignore1.com.error.log warn;
    root /var/www/ignore1.com/;


    include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/php.conf:

    index index.php;
    location /faveicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_cache one;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;

        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

        fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$http_x_access_token;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 30m;
    }

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ignore2.com:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.ignore2.com enjoy.domain1.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/enjoy.error.log warn;
    root /var/www/ignore2.com/;

    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $document_root$fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi.conf;

        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited the title of your thread from "for no reason" because I'm confident there is a good reason it's not working as you expect. To start to diagnose this I suggest you have a default_server that serves a single static page, then configure your domains explicitly. I'd also strip it back to absolute basic, each server / location serving a static block until it works as expected, then slowly add the old config back until you find the error. Once you do that you'll probably work out the answer yourself. If you need more help please edit your post with the latest configuration / information.

Comment: @Tim doesn't matter what I do, If I edit domain2.com to something bogus "testdomaindisabled.com" for example, then add a default server somewhere else and point it to /usr/share/nginx/html (default directory on Archlinux), it STILL goes to that specific server, serves that content, and issues a 200, and what's more bizzare is that kf.domain2.com and ignore1.com, ignore2.com all work 100% correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a typo in the port number, 433 should be 443.